# Invoking isolated langlib function within isolated function in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina, isolation

```
import ballerina/io;

type Person readonly & record {|
    string name;
    int age;
|};

public isolated function main() returns error? {
    string[] fields = ["name", "age", "address"];
    Person p = {name: "John", age: 30};

    string[] validFields = fields.filter(fieldName => p.keys().indexOf(fieldName) > -1);
    io:println(validFields);
}
```

Please consider the above code.
Here `main` function is `isolated` and within that we call another `isolated` function `filter`. But we get an error as shown below.

```
incompatible types: expected an 'isolated' function
```

The error comes when we access the `p` inside the `filter` function.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In this example `filter` in an `isolated` function. When a langlib function that accepts a function argument, it usually has the `@isolatedParam` annotation, which will require the argument function to be `isolated` if the langlib function is called in an `isolated` function. This is to ensure that the `isolated` function continues to call only functions that are `isolated`.

Please check the source. https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/v2201.5.0/langlib/lang.array/src/main/ballerina/array.bal#L130

`p` is a captured variable within the argument function, it's defined outside the function and is neither a final variable nor it is guaranteed to be an immutable value. So `p` cannot be accessed within the isolated function. That is the reason for the error.
If `p` is final and immutable, `p` can be accessed within the isolated function.

```
final readonly & Person p = {name: "John", age: 30};
```